# Adding a column calculated from subset of another column

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset similar to the one created here.

```
data have;
    input date :date. count;
cards;
20APR2012 10
20APR2012 20
20APR2012 20
27APR2012 15
27APR2012 5
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
    by date;
run;
```

I want to create a column containing the sum for each date, so it would look like

```
date          total
20APR2012     50
27APR2012     20
```

I have tried using first. but I think my syntax is off.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `proc means` is for.

```
proc means data=have;
class date;
var count;
output out=want sum=total;
run;
```

Comment: Does SAS allow to formatting the date in the class statement?

Comment: Absolutely, and if multiple values format to one single format they'll be grouped automatically.  If it's already formatted, it will already work this way.  Additionally, you can add a format in the proc.  Additionally, it works with multilabel formats (this is the big difference from the SQL solution), where one row can qualify for multiple categories easily.

Comment: Oh nice... I should be using Proc Means more.

Answer (score 2):

The code below works to give you your desired result.

```
proc sql;
create table wanted_tab as
select
  date format date9., 
  sum(count) as Total
  from have
 group by date;
  ;
quit;
```